# Speeding up Levenshtein distance calculation in Ionic app

Tags: javascript, performance, ionic-framework, nlp, levenshtein-distance

- What I'm doing: I'm developing a mobile dictionary app for a number of languages
- How I'm doing it: Using ionic framework with combination of some angular and some pure js (imported from a working online dictionary site of the same languages)
- The problem: Our search function is an approximate search that uses a Levenstein distance calculator to rank all entries in the dictionary with respect to the query form. When the dictionary has up to 1,500 words, this isn't a problem at all on phones, but when the dictionary has around 10,000 words, there is about a 5-8 second delay before results are shown, despite it being instantaneous on a web browser using "ionic serve". When I run firebug, the javascript that takes the longest time to process are the distance calculations, so my working assumption is that this is where I should start, but I'm open to any suggestions at all.

Here's the distance calculator:

```
/**
 * editDistance.js
 * 
 * A simple Levenshtein distance calculator, except weighted such
 * that insertions at the beginning and deletions at the end cost less.
 *
 * AUTHOR: Pat Littell
 * LAST UPDATED: 2015-05-16
 */

var distanceCalculator = {

insertionCost : 1.0,
deletionCost : 1.0,
insertionAtBeginningCost : 0.11,
deletionAtEndCost : 0.1,
substitutionCost : 1.0,

getEditDistance : function(a, b) {
  if(a.length === 0) return b.length; 
  if(b.length === 0) return a.length; 

  var matrix = [];
 // var currentInsertionCost, currentDeletionCost, currentSubstitutionCost = 0;

  // increment along the first column of each row
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= b.length; i++){
    matrix[i] = [i * this.insertionAtBeginningCost];
  }

  // increment each column in the first row
  var j;
  for(j = 0; j <= a.length; j++){
    matrix[0][j] = j;
  }

  // Fill in the rest of the matrix
  for(i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
    for(j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
        currentInsertionCost = matrix[i][j-1] + this.insertionCost;
        currentSubstitutionCost = matrix[i-1][j-1] + (b.charAt(i-1) != a.charAt(j-1) ? this.substitutionCost : 0);
        currentDeletionCost = matrix[i-1][j] + (j==a.length ? this.deletionAtEndCost : this.deletionCost);            
        matrix[i][j] = Math.min(currentSubstitutionCost, Math.min(currentInsertionCost, currentDeletionCost));

    }
  }

  return matrix[b.length][a.length];
},


// Given a query <a> and a series of targets <bs>, return the least distance to any target
getLeastEditDistance : function(a, bs) {
    var that = this;
    return Math.min.apply(null, bs.map(function(b) {
        return that.getEditDistance(a,b);
    }));
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein

Comment: As a hack, I guess you can define a maximum edit distance and break the nested loops when it passed the limit.`if (matrix[i][j]>4){break;}`. The you need to return the maximum value as the distance!

Comment: @alvas I haven't, but it doesn't look like it would be much faster than what I have already, and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to allow for different costs to insertions at the beginning of words etc like I have in my version. But thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Mehdi, that's a good idea, for some reason when I just put it in, I wasn't getting the same results as before, and it seemed to be missing some words in the dictionary, I'll have to tinker with it a little more before seeing if it will actually work. In any case it's still not getting me the speed I need, but it's a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you have a known dictionary you will get the fastest solution with something like a [Levenshtein Automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton), which will solve this in linear time to get **all** candidates. You can't beat this with a general purpose implementation.

With that said, this implementation of levenshtein distance is a few times faster than yours.

```
function distance(s, t) {
    if (s === t) {
        return 0;
    }
    var n = s.length, m = t.length;
    if (n === 0 || m === 0) {
        return n + m;
    }
    var x = 0, y, py, a, b, c, d, e, f, k;

    var p = new Array(n);

    for (y = 0; y < n;) {
        p[y] = ++y;
    }

    for (; (x + 3) < m; x += 4) {
        var tx0 = t.charCodeAt(x);
        var tx1 = t.charCodeAt(x + 1);
        var tx2 = t.charCodeAt(x + 2);
        var tx3 = t.charCodeAt(x + 3);
        a = x;
        b = x + 1;
        c = x + 2;
        d = x + 3;
        e = x + 4;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            k = s.charCodeAt(y);
            py = p[y];
            if (py < a || b < a) {
                a = (py > b ? b + 1 : py + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (tx0 !== k) {
                    a++;
                }
            }

            if (a < b || c < b) {
                b = (a > c ? c + 1 : a + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (tx1 !== k) {
                    b++;
                }
            }

            if (b < c || d < c) {
                c = (b > d ? d + 1 : b + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (tx2 !== k) {
                    c++;
                }
            }

            if (c < d || e < d) {
                d = (c > e ? e + 1 : c + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (tx3 !== k) {
                    d++;
                }
            }

            p[y] = e = d;
            d = c;
            c = b;
            b = a;
            a = py;
        }
    }

    for (; x < m;) {
        tx0 = t.charCodeAt(x);
        a = x;
        b = ++x;
        for (y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            py = p[y];
            if (py < a || b < a) {
                b = (py > b ? b + 1 : py + 1);
            }
            else {
                if (tx0 !== s.charCodeAt(y)) {
                    b = a + 1;
                }
                else {
                    b = a;
                }
            }
            p[y] = b;
            a = py;
        }
        f = b;
    }

    return f;
}
```

I would also not use `map` in `getLeastEditDistance`, it is very slow. Just use a normal loop. Also `Math.min` with many arguments is not very performant.

Comment: You can check the performance of different general purpose levenshtein implementations here: http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-distance/25

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Levenstein distances by my self and I have not found a good way to improve performance and will not recommend using it in a non-batch application.

I suggest you use another approach by using a search tree. A binary or ternary search tree can also find near match.

A good place to start is those articles:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5819/Ternary-Search-Tree-Dictionary-in-C-Faster-String

or

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68500/Balanced-Binary-Search-Tree-BST-Search-Delete-InOr

The code is relatively simple sp you should not use much time to port it to JavaScript.